# ASP.NET MVC - Issue when receiving the Json response from IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

Please see the screenshot below. I'm returning Json result from a controller to populate a cascading drop-down. The application works perfectly fine when run from the visual studio, but the drop-down doesn't get filtered at all (throws a 404) when run from the iis server. I'm really confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

In the pic, the one on top is when run from VS, and the one in the bottom is when run from the iis through intranet.

I've attached the code below as requested, but like I've mentioned above, it works perfectly fine when run from Visual Studio.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
       public JsonResult FilterByDivision(string divisionId)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ctx)
                {
                    var SubDivResults = (from q in ctx.Test
                                           where q.divId== divisionId
                                           select new Models.SubDivisionDTO
                                           {
                                               SubDivID = q.subdivId,
                        SubDiv = q.SubDiv

                                           }).Distinct().ToList();
                    ajaxLookup.SubDiv = SubDivResults;           


                }
                JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
                    result.Data = ajaxLookup;
                      return result;
                }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

**Jquery**

//Filter By Division

```
$(function () {
$("select#DivisionId").change(function (evt) {
if ($("select#DivisionId").val() != "-1") {
$.ajax({
url: "/AjaxDropDown/FilterByDivision",
type: 'Post',
data: { divisionId: $("select#DivisionId").val() },
success: function (data) {
var subDivItems = "<option value='" + "-1" + "'>" + "Please Select" + "</option>";
$.each(data.subDivisions, function (i, val) {
subDivItems += "<option value='" + val.subDivId + "'>" + val.subDivName + "</option>";
});
$("select#subDivId").empty().html(subDivItems);
}
});
}
});
});
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the c# code that processes the request as well as the javascript ajax call you make. this will help answer this question

Comment: What version of IIS are you running on what OS?

Comment: I've included the code as requested. The IIS runs on windows 2008 server R2. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are making the call from jQuery, for example, check the path because you're getting a 404. You are probably running your application inside a virtual directory and you are calling a absolute path from your javascript.

That is probably your problem for a 404 result.

From your snippet the problem lies probably here:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/AjaxDropDown/FilterByDivision",
    ...
});
```

You should have something probably on this form:

```
$(function () {
    $("select#DivisionId").change(function (evt) {
        var resourceAddress = '@Url.Content("~/AjaxDropDown/FilterByDivision")';

        if ($("select#DivisionId").val() != "-1") {
            $.ajax({
                url: resourceAddress,
                type: 'Post',
                data: {
                    divisionId: $("select#DivisionId").val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    var subDivItems = "<option value='" + "-1" + "'>" + "Please Select" + "</option>";
                    $.each(data.subDivisions, function (i, val) {
                        subDivItems += "<option value='" + val.subDivId + "'>" + val.subDivName + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("select#subDivId").empty().html(subDivItems);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This would give you a relative path every time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Below is how I refer my JQuery. Haven't made much changes. Just as predefined by MVC4. <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")    
</head>  Any suggestions please?

Comment: Hello, your problem is probably here:

`url: "/AjaxDropDown/FilterByDivision",`

You are making a call for a resource in the root of your domain, but in your ISS this resource is not there.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure about your syntax ? Now, I'm getting warnings like conditional compilation turned-off, syntax error, etc. Plus, I can't see any ajax requests on the browser tools even when running from Visual studio. Can I include razor tag inside like that ? Could you please elaborate your code ?

Comment: Just a bit more information. I've written by jquery code inside one of my views. not as a separate script file.

Comment: Sorry, I have update my answer, I was missing some quotes there. JS parser should be happy now with the quotes and semicolon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26965/discussion-between-anderson-fortaleza-and-jundev)

Answer (score 0):

Look in your IIS log files and check the HTTP Substatus Code. It will provide some additional information about what is causing the 404 error. See [The HTTP status code in IIS 7.0, IIS 7.5, and IIS 8.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891). If your substatus code is 0 or 1, you may not have the correct URL or your file may actually be missing from the server. If it's anything else you have other problems and posting the substatus code will help.

If you do have a substatus code of 0 or 1, Anderson Fortaleza is probably correct in his answer.